# How to initialize an array of structs with another stuct?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, backpropagation

Hello I am writing an algorithm for back propagation in c++, it consists of 1 input layer 1 hidden layer and 1 output layer.
I am curious how to initialize my inputlayer, hiddenlayer, and outputlayer.

This is what i got:

```
struct Neuron {
double activation;
double bias;
double *incomingWeights;
};

struct Network {
double *targetLayer;
Neuron *inputLayer;
Neuron *hiddenLayer;
Neuron *outputLayer;
};

ann.inputLayer = malloc(din * sizeof * Neuron); //ERROR
for (int i = 0; i < din; i++) {
    ann.inputLayer[i].activation = 0;
    ann.inputLayer[i].bias = 0;
    ann.inputLayer[i].incomingWeights = NULL;
}

ann.outputLayer = malloc(dout * sizeof * Neuron); //ERROR
for (int i = 0; i < dout; i++) {
    ann.outputLayer[i].activation = 0;
    ann.outputLayer[i].bias = 0;
    ann.outputLayer[i].incomingWeights = new double[dhid];
}
```

din represents the number of neurons in my input layer.
dhid represents the number of neurons in my hidden layer. 
dout repreesnts the number of neurons in my output layer.
i didnt bother showing the initialization of my hidden layer cause its not important
thank you

i wrote //ERROR on the lines where errors are shown according to my IDE(netbeans)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the code you have written? It does have some issues but it helps if you explain yourself rather than we guess.

Comment: If you use `new` instead of `malloc`, the constructor method would be called after memory allocation.  The constructor is where you should initialized the objects.

Comment: main.cpp:138:50: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token that is the error that i am getting it refers to the way i am using malloc, which makes me think i am not using malloc correctly

Comment: Another method is to use `std::vector` and copy the items during the construction of the `vector`.

Comment: Please edit your post to show `main.cpp:138:50`.

Comment: The code posted is legal C.  It shouldn't compile with a C++ compiler, however.  Which leads to the question: should it be C or C++.  If the intent is to write code in C, then the label should be C (and if the above code doesn't compile, it's probably because you're using a C++ compiler).  If the intent is to write code in C++, then there should be no pointers and no dynamic allocation in the code, at least not for the parts we've been shown.

Comment: In general, we need the error message as well as the location; in this case, the errors are trivial.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15961835/1084416).

Answer (score 3):

First, you never want to do default initializations in calling code, you can create a constructor for your struct and do it there:

```
struct Neuron {
   Neuron() : activation(0.0), bias(0.0), incomingWeights(0) {}
   double activation;
   double bias;
   double *incomingWeights;
};
```

Then (since this is C++)

```
for (int i = 0; i < din; i++) {
   ann.inputLayer[i] = new Neuron[din];
```

You should use `new` over `malloc` in C++, though if you ever did need `malloc` your statement would need to be fixed, to:

```
ann.inputLayer = (Neuron*)malloc(din * sizeof(Neuron));
```

Comment: @jamalsabs My pleasure, esp. since it's neuroscience. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use `malloc` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184540/16287).

As a *minimal change to what you have*, change this:

```
ann.inputLayer = malloc(din * sizeof * Neuron);
```

To this:

```
ann.inputLayer = new Neuron[din];
```

`new` here is more clear for readers of your code, performs construction when needed, and returns the correct pointer type.

(Same with the `dout` line)

*Edit:*

You would also likely find `std::vector` *much* easier to manage over pointers.

Comment: No.  Don't use `new[]` either.  `inputLayer` should be an `std::vector`.  (In fact, I don't think there should be any pointers in this code.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I completely agree with your reasoning, although your suggestion would require changes in unposted code.  That would be a good lesson for another day.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: the reason you're getting errors is because you are compiling C code with a C++ compiler.  `malloc` returns a `void*`.  In C, this converts implicitly to any other pointer type; in C++, you need an explicit conversion.

Except that, as others are saying as well, you should *never* use `malloc` in C++ (unless for reasons of compatibility with C—i.e. you are passing the pointer to a function written in C which will call `free` on it).  In fact, in the little you've shown, there should be no pointers and no dynamic allocation whatsoever: define your types, add constructors, and when you need more than one, use `std::vector`.